# Read continuously and delete characters between CR and CRLF from file to buffers then write to new file

Tags: c

i`m trying to allocate a file of size 836 into a buffer of size 200 continuously and search for characters between a CR and CRLF then skip them and write to new file!

**File like this**

```
CR
CRLF
1bb8CR
CRLF
!DOC...........text text etx>
html text ...........text text etx...........text text etx....>CR
CRLF
1704CR
CRLF
texte classes=====.......>
.................>
CR
CRLF
0CR
CRLF
CR
CRLF
/EOF
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int       BUF_SIZE = 200;
    FILE            *fptr_in;
    FILE            *fptr_out;
    char            buffer[BUF_SIZE + 1]={0};
    char            CRLF[BUF_SIZE]={0};
    char            lastChar = '\0';
    int             i = 0, j = 0, z = 0, n = 0, sub;
    size_t          result = 0;
    long            lSize;
    if((fptr_in = fopen("LogFile_ProxyBufferContents_FJ_small.html", "r")) == NULL){
        printf ("\nError opening file");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        while(fgetc(fptr_in) != EOF){
            n++;
        }
        if(feof(fptr_in)){
            printf_s("\nTotal number of bytes read: %d", n);
            printf_s(" Bytes.\n");
        }
    }
    if((fptr_out = fopen("LogFile_ProxyBufferContents_Out.html", "w")) == NULL){
        fclose(fptr_in);
        return 0;
    }
    // Obtain the File size
    fseek(fptr_in, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(fptr_in);
    rewind(fptr_in);
    // Buffer Null check
    if(buffer == NULL){
        fclose(fptr_in);
        return 0;
    }
    // Read File into Buffer by result size
    while((result = fread_s(buffer, bufSize, 1, bufSize, fptr_in)) != 0){
        while(i < (long)result){
            if(buffer[i] == '\r' && buffer[i + 1] == '\n'){
                if(buffer[i + 6] == '\n'){
                    i += 6;
                }
                else if(buffer[i + 6] == '\r'){
                    i += 7;
                }
            }
            else{
                sub = z -i;
                CRLF[j] = buffer[i];
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }

    fclose(fptr_in);
    fclose(fptr_out);
    //printf("\nBuffer after removing CRLF %s\n", CRLF);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So if the block of CR CRLF at the beginning no problem but at the end without use buffer [i+6] can't figure it out?

My idea is if `i` and `i+1` is true then check if next 6 `buffer[i] != '\0'`,(i use 6 because every time guarantee that between CR and CRLF came 3 or 4 characters) if so for example if the End of the buffer is index of 5 after CR and the next CRLF is located into the next Buffer at index 2, mean: buffer one: texte...text>CR170\0 and next buffer 2 is 4CRCRLF then rest of html...
I'm new to programming, how to do jump to next read `buffer2` and skip the char before CR and keep the process work of other places into file, Sorry for my English.
Any help please?

**Edited:**
Maybe i couldn't explain correctly... I wanted to locate the first CRLf and second one then skip the middle hex number, in my case it's a socket buffer through proxy which come always with a Chunk's length surrounded by CRLF. Can you suggest what should i do? 
If the Chunk length come in top or middle or last is ok, but if the chunk length is separated in half i stack!!

++++Example File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw62NZwp1GSnaG1ydXVHREZibEE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your coding does not match your problem description. Why do you check buffer[I+6]? This is not part of your problem description. Also: checking buffer[I+1] at line 3 might read beyond buffer.

Comment: Thank you for replay to my problem, maybe i couldn`t explain correctly... I wanted to locate the first CRLf and second one then skip the middle hex number, in my case it`s a socket buffer through proxy which come always with a Chunk`s length surrounded by CRLF. Can you suggest what should i do? Thanks

Comment: Chunked HTML? What do you want to achieve? Do want to read a chunked HTML stream and output a non-chunked HTML stream?

Comment: Actually, i made a Proxy tool which download a html contents from a website, at my network i didn't get the chunk length into the html data by other network under gateway i got the chunk length into html, but i can't check my self, so i use the html data which include the chunk like an input file then delete the chunk length...I know the chunk is return at the top of socket buffer but for studding more, i assumed that chunk may come at the middle or cut in half into 1st and 2nd buffer....

Comment: @WernerHenze yes i want to read a chunked HTML and output a non-chunked HTML, assuming that chunk could be on top of file or at end of file, but in my case i stream the file using a buffer, assuming too if the chunk would cut into 2 parts, the first part at end of buffer, and second part at the top of next buffer... In this case i couldn't solve it!

Comment: Google for "HTML chunked" or "RFC HTML chunked", read how chunks work and then implement it. Don't write code that scans for \r\n and searches for numbers between \r\n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full code to my problem, i wanted to share in case help some one...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

const char* LOG_FILE = "ORIGIN.html";
const char* OUT_FILE = "Out.html";

//#define BUF_SIZE 200
#define BUF_SIZE 4096

// Search for CRLF line endings, if CRLF found its return the position of the next CRNL, else return none found
int find_CRLF(TCHAR* buffer, int size) {
    int result;
    for(TCHAR* pos = buffer; size > 1; ++pos, --size) {
        // Return the line followed by CRLF 
        if(pos[0] == '\r') {
            if(pos[1] == '\n') {
                result = pos - buffer;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    // None is found
    return -1;
}

// Check the given string whether a Hex number
int is_HEX(TCHAR* buffer, int size) {
    if(! size){
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if(! iswxdigit(buffer[i])) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //If buffer is_HEX return True
    return 1;
}

// Write the line from input to output if isn't HEX
// buffer input data assumed to start at new line after CRLF or begining of File
int get_Line(TCHAR* buffer, int size, TCHAR* out, int* byteCopied) {
    // Declare line by CRLF endings
    int line_end = find_CRLF(buffer, size);
    // If no end could be found return -1
    if(line_end < 0){
        return line_end;
    }
    // If line is_HEX skip 2 lines
    if(is_HEX(buffer, line_end)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Hex skipped\n");
        return line_end + 2; /* skip */
    }
    // Else !is_HEX, copy buffer
    for(int i = 0; i < line_end + 2; ++i, ++(*byteCopied)) {    // Dereference pointer & increment the value pointer
        if(buffer[i] == '\r') {     
            return line_end + 2;
        }
        out[i] = buffer[i]; /* copy buffer*/
    }
    return line_end + 2;
}

// Return number of bytes processed, & reminder is non COMPLETE LINES
int filter_Buffer(TCHAR* buffer, int size, TCHAR* out, int* byteCopied) {
    TCHAR* pos = buffer;
    *byteCopied = 0;
    for(;;) {
        int next_start = get_Line(pos, size, out + *byteCopied, byteCopied);//out+address, value)
        if(next_start < 0) {
            return pos - buffer;
        }
        pos += next_start;
        size -= next_start;
    }
}

// Handle the Reminder, return Number of unprocessed Bytes in in_buf or -1 on EOF
int filter_BufferFile(FILE* input, FILE* output, TCHAR* in_buf, int in_pos) {
    TCHAR out_buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int size = fread(in_buf + in_pos, 1, BUF_SIZE - in_pos, input);
    size += in_pos;
    if(! size) {
        return -1;
    }
    int byteCopied;
    int end_pos = filter_Buffer(in_buf, size, out_buf, &byteCopied);
    if(end_pos) {
        for(int i = 0; i < size - end_pos; ++i) {
            in_buf[i] = in_buf[i + end_pos];
        }
    }
    else {
        if(size == BUF_SIZE) {
            fwrite(in_buf, 1, size, output);
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            /* no newline at EOF */
            get_Line(in_buf, size, out_buf, &byteCopied);
        }
    }
    //If no check for buffer[i&i+1]!=\r&\n -> minus 2 bytes 
    //fwrite(out_buf, 1, byteCopied-2, output);
    fwrite(out_buf, 1, byteCopied, output);
    return size - end_pos;
}

// Call untill the whole input file is processed
void filter_File(FILE* input, FILE* output) {
    char in_buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int in_pos = 0;
    do {
        in_pos = filter_BufferFile(input, output, in_buf, in_pos);
    } while(in_pos >= 0);
}

int main(void) {

    FILE* input = fopen(LOG_FILE, "r");
    if(! input) {
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* output = fopen(OUT_FILE, "w");
    if(! output) {
        return 1;
    }

    filter_File(input, output);

    fclose(output);
    fclose(input);

    system("pause");
}
```

Demo File:

[Download the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw62NZwp1GSnejdkaHFrOEdZTnc/edit?usp=sharing)